# SSAS unmarking as date table The Column object 'Period[RowNumber-2662979B-1795-4F74-8F37-]' is a system object and may not be modified

Tags: ssas-tabular

When trying to unmark the date table 'Period' I get the following error:

> ============================
>
> ## Error Message:
>
> Failed to save modifications to the server. Error returned: 'Unable to
>   modify system objects: The Column object
>   'Period[RowNumber-2662979B-1795-4F74-8F37-]' is a system
>
> ### object and may not be modified. '.
>
> Failed to save modifications to the server. Error returned: 'Unable to modify  system objects: The Column
>   object 'Period[RowNumber-2662979B-1795-4F74-8F37-]' is a
>   system object and may not be modified. '.
>
> ============================
>
> ## Call Stack:
>
> at Microsoft.AnalysisServices.BackEnd.DataModelingSandboxTabular.ExecuteEngineCodeInBackground(OperationType
>   type, Boolean cancellable, AMOCode code, Boolean raiseEvents)    at
>   Microsoft.AnalysisServices.BackEnd.DataModelingSandboxTabular.DoExecuteEngineCode(OperationType
>   type, OperationCancellability cancellable, AMOCode code, Boolean
>   raiseEvents)    at
>   Microsoft.AnalysisServices.BackEnd.DataModelingSandbox.ExecuteEngineCode(OperationType
>   type, OperationCancellability cancellable, AMOCode code, Boolean
>   raiseEvents)    at
>   Microsoft.AnalysisServices.BackEnd.SandboxTransaction.CommitInternal(Boolean
>
> ### finalCommit)
>
> at Microsoft.AnalysisServices.BackEnd.SandboxTransaction.CommitInternal(Boolean
>   finalCommit)    at
>   Microsoft.AnalysisServices.Common.SandboxEditor.MarkAsDateTableChecked(String
>   tableId)
>
> ============================

I have another cube with a similar date table, but I can do this witouth any issues

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this by deleting my date table 'Period' and re importing it.